# rCharts tooltip content for multiplie lines

Tags: r, tooltip, shiny, rcharts

I am a simple R coder with almost no experience coding in HTML of javascript, so I'm having a hard time understanding the wrappers for the tool tip customization code.

I have 2 time series that I've plotted with rCharts lineWithFocusChart, now I want to customize the tooltip to look like this:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/nvd3-line-chart-output.html

Here is my code so far:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$myChart <- renderChart({
    select<-as.numeric(input$radioTS)

    out <- data.frame(Actuals[,select], Fits[,select], mmmyyyy)
    colnames(out) <- c("Actuals","Fits","Date")
    data<-melt(out,id.vars = 'Date')
    data$Date <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(data$Date)) * 1000

    p1 <- nPlot(
      value ~ Date,
      group = 'variable',
      data = data,
      type = 'lineWithFocusChart',
      width = 650,
      height = 500
    )

    p1$addParams(dom = 'myChart')
    p1$xAxis(tickFormat = "#!function(d) {return d3.time.format('%b %Y')(new Date(d))}!#")
    p1$x2Axis(tickFormat = "#!function(d) {return d3.time.format('%Y')(new Date(d))}!#")
    p1$yAxis(tickFormat = "#!function(d) {return d3.format('0,.0')(d)}!#")

    return(p1) 
  })
})
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shiny example referenced uses nvd3 `interactiveGuideline` feature.  To employ this in rCharts, you can `p1$chart(useInteractiveGuideline=TRUE)`, but due to this [nvd3 issue](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/283) the `lineWithFocusChart` does not yet offer this functionality, so for now we will be limited to `lineChart`.

Unfortunately, nvd3 currently does not support customization of the interactiveGuideline, since this [pull request](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/pull/313) has not yet been accepted.  However, you can get a pretty decent looking tooltip by proper naming as shown in this [example](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/inst/libraries/nvd3/examples.R#L33-L63).

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

      output$myChart <- renderChart({
        select<-as.numeric(input$radioTS)

        out <- data.frame(Actuals[,select], Fits[,select], mmmyyyy)
        colnames(out) <- c("Actuals","Fits","Date")
        data<-melt(out,id.vars = 'Date')
        data$Date <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(data$Date)) * 1000

        p1 <- nPlot(
          value ~ Date,
          group = 'variable',
          data = data,
          type = 'lineChart',  # see explanation for why not lineWithFocusChart
          width = 650,
          height = 500
        )

        p1$addParams(dom = 'myChart')
        p1$xAxis(tickFormat = "#!function(d) {return d3.time.format('%b %Y')(new Date(d))}!#")
        #commented x2Axis out since only lineChart
        #p1$x2Axis(tickFormat = "#!function(d) {return d3.time.format('%Y')(new Date(d))}!#")
        p1$yAxis(tickFormat = "#!function(d) {return d3.format('0,.0')(d)}!#")
        p1$chart(useInteractiveGuideline = TRUE)

        return(p1) 
      })
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've seen this before:
`p1$chart(useInteractiveGuideline = TRUE)`
but I didn't realize it wasn't available specifically for lineWithFocusChart. 

Follow up question: do you know how to add in the vertical line as well?